# Ajax Form submission working on Chrome but does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm currently working with PHP and I've added a form that is supposed to take  information on a form and submit the form.

Up on clicking check out a modal pop up opens which asks the user to register and up on clicking sign up the user is redirected to dashboard page with logged in account.

Here's my code:

```
 <button type="submit" id="clientRegister1" class="btn btn-raised btn-block btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
```

My Ajax code

```
 // Condition for Client Register with ajax

 $('#clientRegister1').on('click', function(e) {
    var name = document.getElementById("clientname").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("clientEmail2").value;
    var contact = document.getElementById("clientcontact").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("clientpassword").value;
    var repassword = document.getElementById("clientConfirmPassword").value;
    var termsandconditions = document.getElementById("termsandconditions").value;

    if(name ==''){
        swal("Name not filled out", "", "warning");
        e.preventDefault();
    }else if(email ==''){
        swal("Email not filled out", "", "warning");
        e.preventDefault();
    }else if(contact ==''){
        swal("Contact not filled out", "", "warning");
        e.preventDefault();
    }else if(password == ''){
        swal("Password not filled out", "", "warning");
        e.preventDefault();
    }else if(repassword == ''){
        swal("Confirm Password not filled out", "", "warning");
        e.preventDefault();
    }else if(password != repassword) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal("Password do not Match!", "", "warning");
    }else {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Client/createClient",
            data: {uname: name, uemail: email, ucontact: contact, upassword: password},
            cache: false,
            success:
            function (data) {
                // window.location.reload();
                document.getElementById("inputEmail").value = data;
                $('#formsubmit_order').submit();
            }
       });
    }
 });
```

The code works COMPLETELY fine and submits all the data and redirects to the page specified in Google chrome but does not work on Firefox. Up on clicking submit the page just refreshes on Firefox.

Comment: Could you try seeing Console tab in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your submitting your form here so it will post when clicked.

```
<button type="submit" id="clientRegister1" class="btn btn-raised btn-block btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
```

When using ajax, I like to specify a method name on an input type button, with `return false` so it never posts after the method... so...

Amend to:

```
<input type="button" id="clientRegister1" onclick="register(event); return false;" class="btn btn-raised btn-block btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
```

and js...

```
function register(e){
     var name = document.getElementById("clientname").value;
var email = document.getElementById("clientEmail2").value;
var contact = document.getElementById("clientcontact").value;
var password = document.getElementById("clientpassword").value;
var repassword = document.getElementById("clientConfirmPassword").value;
var termsandconditions = document.getElementById("termsandconditions").value;



if(name ==''){
    swal("Name not filled out", "", "warning");
    e.preventDefault();
}else if(email ==''){
    swal("Email not filled out", "", "warning");
    e.preventDefault();
}else if(contact ==''){
    swal("Contact not filled out", "", "warning");
    e.preventDefault();
}else if(password == ''){
    swal("Password not filled out", "", "warning");
    e.preventDefault();
}else if(repassword == ''){
    swal("Confirm Password not filled out", "", "warning");
    e.preventDefault();
}else if(password != repassword) {
    e.preventDefault();
    swal("Password do not Match!", "", "warning");
}else {

//  alert("working");
//  e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Client/createClient",
        data: {uname: name, uemail: email, ucontact: contact, upassword: password},
        cache: false,
        success:
        function (data) {

                    // window.location.reload();
                    document.getElementById("inputEmail").value = data;
                    $('#formsubmit_order').submit();

                }

            });
}

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Security concern such as cross domain, non secure ssl page request often known for this problem. When request and response header does not match this kind occurs

Their are 3 major area to look into

1. .htaccess
2. Ajax file you are calling page from
3. PHP page giving response to Ajax

Lets look in to these files one by one, first root .htaccess add these lines if does not exist. You can change it here or make this changes in step 3

```
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Referrer-Policy "origin"
  </IfModule>
```

Second Ajax function

```
    $.ajax( {
      type: 'POST',
      url: yourForm.attr( 'action' ),
      data: yourForm.serializeArray(),
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      async: true,
      crossDomain: false,
      headers: {
                  'accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                  'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST',
              },      
      xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },      
      success: function(data) {
            if (data.code == '200') {
            $('.bg-success').removeClass('hidden');    
            $('#message').html(data.message);    
            document.getElementById("yourForm").reset();
            }
      }
});
```

Tell the browser he content type of your page and in what format data you will accept in header object. you also need to tell the browser access control allow method and origin. as you are dealing with form use content type as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Now let look at last step PHP file

```
         // Send Ajax Reply   
            $reply = [];
            $reply['code'] = 200;
            $reply['message'] = 'We have received your message.';
```

Skip this two lines if you already added .htaccess

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Referrer-Policy: origin');
```

Same file

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    echo json_encode($reply);
```